# Straighten all bone chains in an armature

Tags: scripting, armature, bones

I have a hair rig with a lot of bone chains in a single armature. The bone chains are curved in their rest pose, matching the hair curving down around the character's head. I want to straighten out all the bone chains and save it as a new pose. The problem is that rest pose is already seen as 0,0,0 for rotation. How can I straighten these bone chains?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Script to align child edit bones to the selected edit bone. (The base of hair bones)  To use: have your rig in edit mode, and the desired base bone(s) of hair bone chains selected..  As with all scripts save first.

```
import bpy
context = bpy.context
for eb in context.selected_editable_bones:
    parent = eb        
    v = (eb.tail - eb.head).normalized()

    while len(parent.children):
        bone = parent.children[0]
        bone.head = parent.tail
        bone.tail = parent.tail + bone.length * v
        parent = bone
```

Answer (score 2):

One option to do that would be to use *Auto IK*, which is located in *3D Viewport > Toolshelf > Options tab* (use <kbd>T</kbd> to toggle open/close the *Toolshelf*). When *Auto IK* is turned on, you can select last bone of the chain and pull it straight to any direction you want.

Alternatively (necessary if your hair chains are directly connected to head), you could use [IK Solvers](https://www.blender.org/manual/rigging/constraints/tracking/ik_solver.html). In *Pose Mode*, select the last bone of the chain, key <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>, select *To New Empty*, and in the *Properties panel > Bone Constraints tab*, set the chain length to the right amount of bones. Then, you can use the empty object created earlier to pull the chain straight.

Answer (score 1):

To align bones regardless of parenting you can temporarily add a `copy rotation constraint` for each bone, then apply the visual transform by selecting the bone and clicking `CTRL+A` > `Apply visual transform to pose` and `CTRL+A` again > `Apply pose as rest pose`for it to take effect in the edit mode as well, then you can delete the `copy rotation constraint`.

Comment: Not sure what you are implying re _"If don't want to mess with your bones parenting""_???  Neither of the other answers change bone hierarchy

Comment: I meant that your script required that the bones be parented to the bone you want them to be aligned to, in my situation that wasn't the case. anyways, I can delete my answer if it will confuse anyone, since the script solution had nailed it already.

Comment: NP, . Def. no need to remove answer.  Little confusing to me,  as bone chain implies parenting   Was seeking clarification  _To align bones regardless of parenting_  maybe?