# How to Flatten a vertex path (a list of connected edges) into a straight line while keeping distances?

Tags: modeling, vertices

I'm trying to develop some custom close-body clothing for my characters.
For that purpose I tried to "flatten" some half circle (meshes) into straight lines that can be easily extruded then sewed to other parts of the clothing.
However the only method I have is the "Scale to Axis" method which is just a projection.

A projection does not preserve the original distance between the vertices.
Is there a (simple) method for flattening a half curve into a straight line while preserving distances?

if not can someone suggest a python script that can achieve the same thing?

NB: here's an article on the subject:
[Addons to straighten edges in Blender](https://www.blendernation.com/2018/01/11/5-ways-straighten-edges-blender/)
However, the above article is old and the tools it mentions (LoopTools, for example) just perform the classic Scale to Axis flattening.
EDIT 1 (some screenshots of the "Bad" Scale to Zero flattening technique:
[image: Two half circles of the same length (units)]
[image: The result of Applying S -> X -> 0 (Scale to Zero)]
As you can see in the last picture, Scale to Zero DOES NOT preserve the path length. It's just a projection!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello :). Just for clarity, could you please add some screenshots to illustrate?

Comment: See the edits (thanks for the comment)!

Comment: Hey :). This answer could help: [Transform cylinder to flat plane](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/185091/78972)

Comment: @JachymMichal was looking for that one... similarly with bones https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/54134/straighten-all-bone-chains-in-an-armature/54151#54151  Kinda need to know which  vert to keep in place and a vector to align to.

Comment: Hi@JachymMichal  indeed, the script works ... only for a full circle. How can I modify it to be used for a half circle?[code]import bpy
from math import atan2,sqrt

cyl = bpy.context.object
if cyl:
    flt = cyl.copy()
    me = flt.data.copy()
    flt.data = me    
    
    bpy.context.collection.objects.link(flt)
    
min_r = 100000
    
for v in me.vertices:
    [x,y,z] = v.co
    r =  v.co.xy.length
    theta = atan2(x,y)
    v.co = (theta,r,z)
    min_r = min([r,min_r])
 
for v in me.vertices:
    v.co.x *= min_r  
    v.co.y -= min_r
flt.location.y += min_r[/code]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I see I'm late, but here's my take on this problem:

```
import bpy, bmesh
from functools import reduce
from mathutils import Vector

mesh = bpy.context.edit_object.data
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(mesh)
active = bm.select_history.active

found = {}  # key: vertex object, value: number of connected vertices, which are selected

def recursive_add(found_vertex):
    found[found_vertex] = 0
    for edge in found_vertex.link_edges:
        for vertex_candidate in edge.verts:
            if vertex_candidate is not found_vertex and vertex_candidate.select:
                found[found_vertex] += 1
                if vertex_candidate not in found:
                    recursive_add(vertex_candidate)

recursive_add(active)
ends = [vertex for vertex, connections in found.items() if connections == 1]
origin = ends[0].co
offset = ends[1].co - origin
individual_offsets = [0]
current_path_length = 0

def analyze_path(a, b):
    global current_path_length
    distance = (a.co - b.co).length
    individual_offsets.append(current_path_length + distance)
    current_path_length += distance
    return b

reduce(analyze_path, found)

# Edit: as @batFINGER mentioned, OP asks to keep the original length of the path:
ratio = current_path_length / offset.length
offset *= ratio

for v, individual_offset in zip(found, individual_offsets):
    v.co = origin + (individual_offset / current_path_length) * offset

bmesh.update_edit_mesh(mesh)
```

at least one of selected vertices has to be active, and it only works in vertex selection mode:

[image]

Edit: as pointed by **batFINGER**, this didn't keep the length of the path, so I added a small update:

[image]

Comment: Of opinion OP wanted to keep edge length. If that was half circle  being collapsed to diameter, the semi circle would have length pi * r whereas the diameter is 2 * r.

Comment: @batFINGER, YEP, well said. But thank you for posting @MarkusvonBroady!

Comment: @batFINGER ah, indeed, I intended to ask if that's the case but forgot and assumed he was imprecise and intended to keep the proportions. I'll update the code in a moment.

Comment: still worth a UV.  Makes sense to use two end points to get alignment. Easy enough to scale later.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady in Blender 2.91 I get this: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Text", line 21, in <module>
  File "/Text", line 14, in recursive_add
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'link_edges'

Comment: Requires an active vert. Edit mode vert select mode, see in screenshot the lighter top vert is active.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady, PLEASE, if you could adapt your code to work on HALF circles (or any open convex path), i'd love to accept your answer.

Comment: @N.Wells did you try the code? It works for me on half of a circle: https://i.imgur.com/tW9MJsf.gif here's without the other vertices: https://i.imgur.com/Iaa6THj.gif make sure one vertex is active (white)

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady, I meant an OPEN half circle. I'm sure I can adapt it myself. But i guess the others need to know too.

Comment: @N.Wells isn't the one here open? https://i.imgur.com/Iaa6THj.gif

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady, Indeed it works. I needed to have an "active vertex" (i.e. the last vertex). Thanks a lot for your answer and time.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady, here are my observations (to make it more perfect): 1) User must make sure that ALL scale transforms have been applied (otherwise) the resulting (unwrapped) path will be scaled; 2) for simplification, the "offset" vector can just be the normalized vector between the two ends of the original path; in that case, the new vectors/coords are just (vector) multiples of this normalized (offset); no need for ratios; 3) (optional) the median point of the selection can be computed before and after the stretching, so that the resulting path can be "centered" just like the original path

Comment: @N.Wells if the ratios aren't needed, then all you need is summing the lengths of selected edges, creating a new edge with that length, and subdividing it. But I thought you need rations to preserve data like this: https://i.imgur.com/fEb9zZV.gif

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady, look, you already have the distances to the origin in the individual offsets array; then each vertex in the found array will get its new coordinates set as a vector multiple of its individual offset and the normalized offset vector thus preserving the distances. I did the test using this approach and it works. The code is much easier to read.

Comment: @N.Wells please paste updated code in pastebin/hastebin etc. and I'll look into it.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady, here's the link: https://pastebin.pl/view/1ec49d31

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120488/discussion-between-markus-von-broady-and-n-wells).

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady, would love to, but it's Saturday, and I need to think about other things than coding (you know what I mean ...).

Answer (score 5):

After long hours, here's an answer to my OWN question, thanks to comments from @Jachym Michal and @batFINGER.

```
import bpy
import math

def rotatePoint(centerPoint,point,angle):
    """Rotates a point around another centerPoint. Angle is in degrees.
    Rotation is counter-clockwise"""
    temp_point = point[0]-centerPoint[0] , point[1]-centerPoint[1]
    temp_point = ( temp_point[0]*math.cos(angle)-temp_point[1]*math.sin(angle) , temp_point[0]*math.sin(angle)+temp_point[1]*math.cos(angle))
    temp_point = temp_point[0]+centerPoint[0] , temp_point[1]+centerPoint[1]
    return temp_point

def crossProduct(a, b):
    c = [a[1]*b[2] - a[2]*b[1],
         a[2]*b[0] - a[0]*b[2],
         a[0]*b[1] - a[1]*b[0]]

    return c

def dotProduct(a, b):
    c = a[0]*b[0] + a[1]*b[1]+ a[2]*b[2]
    return c

cyl = bpy.context.object
if cyl:
    flt = cyl.copy()
    me = flt.data.copy()
    flt.data = me    
    
assert(len(me.vertices) >= 3)

verts = me.vertices
Nvert = len(me.vertices)
print('Nvert=', Nvert)

nVertRots = 0

for n in range(Nvert - 1, 1, -1):
    print('Vertex:',n)
    v1 = verts[n - 1].co - verts[n - 2].co

    v2 = verts[n].co - verts[n-1].co

    v1mag = math.sqrt(v1.x * v1.x + v1.y * v1.y + v1.z * v1.z)

    v1norm = [v1.x/v1mag , v1.y/v1mag , v1.z/v1mag]


    v2mag = math.sqrt(v2.x * v2.x + v2.y * v2.y + v2.z * v2.z)


    v2norm = [v2.x/v2mag , v2.y/v2mag , v2.z/v2mag]


    res = v1norm[0] * v2norm[0] + v1norm[1] * v2norm[1] + v1norm[2] * v2norm[2]

    angle = math.acos(res)
    
    cross = crossProduct(v1norm, v2norm)
    sign = dotProduct([0,0,1], cross)
    if sign < 0:
        angle = -angle
        
    print('Angle(1,2):', angle)
    
    nVertRots += 1
    for m in range(n, Nvert, +1):
        v2rot = rotatePoint([verts[n - 1].co.x, verts[n - 1].co.y],[verts[m].co.x, verts[m].co.y], -angle)
        verts[m].co = (v2rot[0], v2rot[1], verts[0].co.z)


print('nVertRots:',nVertRots)
if nVertRots > 0:
    bpy.context.collection.objects.link(flt)
```

[image: Initial half Circle]

[image: Flatten path]

Comment: A heads up that vectors in blender eg `v = ob.location` have vector operations built in... eg `v.dot((1, 1, 0))` and `v.length` and `v.cross(v)` and `v.normalized()` etc.

Comment: @batFINGER thanks. I was in a hurry. Hopefully somebody will put it into an add-on (fingers crossed).

Answer (score 3):

**Scriptless solution**

Go to Edit -> Preferences... Add-ons, and enable **MeasureIt** and **LoopTools**

Now select a path that interests you, press <kbd>N</kbd> for *Numbers Panel*, click on *View* tab, then expand *MeasureIt* panel at the bottom. Choose a *Sum* group and click on *Segment* button:

[image]

Then scroll down to the *Totals* section to see the total length:

[image]

You can scroll back up to *Items* section to change the precision if needed:

[image]

Right-click your mesh, and from **LoopTools** choose **Gstretch**:

[image]

Change from *Spread evenly* to just *Spread* to keep proportions, then press <kbd>S</kbd> for scaling, <kbd>/</kbd> to divide current length, and type the length you see on the right on the *MeasureIt* panel. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to confirm, then press <kbd>S</kbd> again and this time type the length we had before *Gstretching*: in this case `3.14`. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to confirm.

Comment: That's a solution I was waiting for... I know there must be a way without scripting. Great

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady, great post. However, when you have to do it on dozens of path (at different angles), you'll tire fast. I think someone may contact the LoopTools team to include your script in the next release.

Answer (score 3):

**YAF one.**

_Also late to the party, cooked a GPU, can report 2.91 runs with a Gforce 220 lol  _

For a string of edges can use the method from [How can I sort vertex positions sequentially indices in a closed area?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/191649/how-can-i-sort-vertex-positions-sequentially-indices-in-a-closed-area) to fill the edges. The new face will have edges in its winding order. The new edge to close path is used to set order.

[Face edges angle - python](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/203249/face-edges-angle-python/203355)

[image]

Added a simple UI to also make it "without scripting" 8)_  (*Be a quick task  re-jigging to use code from [@MVB's excellent answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/214064/15543)*)

To use, select a single vert of the edge string, and the axis to align to. Keeps the selected vert in place.

```
import bpy
import bmesh
from mathutils import Matrix
from itertools import cycle, islice

def main(op, context, align):
    def con_edges(vert):
        x, s = set(), set(vert.link_edges)
        while s - x: # edges growing
            x, s  = s, s.union(
                e for le in s 
                for v in le.verts 
                for e in v.link_edges
                if len(v.link_edges) < 3)
        return list(x)

    ob = context.edit_object
    me = ob.data    
    bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)
    av = bm.select_history.active
    if not isinstance(av, bmesh.types.BMVert):
        op.report({'INFO'}, "Select a vert")
        return {'CANCELLED'}
    # keep at active vert location.
    loc = av.co.copy()
    edges = set(bm.edges)
        
    f = bmesh.ops.contextual_create(
            bm,
            geom=con_edges(av),
            )["faces"][0]
    # will throw error if cyclic.
    new_edge =  (set(bm.edges) - edges).pop()
    edges = f.edges[:]
    for e in bm.edges:
        e.select_set(e in edges)

    i = edges.index(new_edge) + 1
    # direction
    if align == 'ENDS':
        vec = (new_edge.verts[1].co - new_edge.verts[0].co).normalized()
    elif align in 'XYZ':
        vec = Matrix.Identity(3)['XYZ'.index(align)]
    # edge loop around face    
    loop = [(v, e, e.calc_length()) for v, e in islice(cycle(zip(f.verts, f.edges)),i, i + len(f.edges) - 1)]
    for v0, e, l in loop:
        #v0 = f.verts[edges.index(e)]
        v1 = e.other_vert(v0)
        v1.co = v0.co + l * vec
    #remove face link edge & move back so vert "doesn't appear to move"
    bm.edges.remove(new_edge)
    bm.transform(
        Matrix.Translation((loc - av.co))
        )
    
    bmesh.update_edit_mesh(me)
    return {'FINISHED'}

class StraightenEdgeOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Straighten Edges"""
    bl_idname = "mesh.straighten_edges"
    bl_label = "Straighten Edges"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}
    align : bpy.props.EnumProperty(
            items=[
                ('X', 'X Axis', ''),
                ('Y', 'Y Axis', ''),
                ('Z', 'Z Axis', ''),
                ('ENDS', 'Segment Ends', ''),
                ],
            name="Align",
            default = 'ENDS',
            )
    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        layout.prop(self, "align", expand=True)
    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.edit_object is not None and context.mode.startswith('EDIT_MESH')

    def execute(self, context):
        return main(self, context, self.align)

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(StraightenEdgeOperator)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(StraightenEdgeOperator)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```